# How can I track send progress using libusb_bulk_transfer with libusb?

Tags: data-transfer, libusb-1.0

Given an application using libusb calling 'libusb_bulk_transfer' how can I track progress of how much has been sent over a data buffer to the end device?

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution? 

- 7 years and 9 months later -_-